# Using an Interface as a Parameter Type For Method, Can this work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, model-view-controller, interface

my question is, if you have a method of the form:
public bool ProcessAggregation(IAggregatePoint point) { #do stuff }
And a class, NetworkAggregation, implementing IAggregatePoint. Can you call the method like:
ProcessAggregation(point) where point here is a NetworkAggregation instance?
Also, if not possible with interfaces, could inheritance of an abstract base class work? Meaning any object inheriting from the abstract base class would be passible into the method?
I am reluctant to alter the classes with inheritance as they are database schemas for a MySql database/ used with EntityFramework.
Thanks!
Network aggregation is implemented like:

```
public class NetworkAggregation : IAggregatePoint
{
    public DateTime? AssessmentDate {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string DUPValue {get; set;}
    //And so on, other properties not specified in IAggregatePoint
}
```

and IAggregatePoint is implemented like:

```
public interface IAggregatePoint
{
    public DateTime? AssessmentDate {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: A good way to find the answer to this is to **_try it out_**, particularly by stepping through your code in the debugger

Comment: I agree, however I am getting error before runtime so I'm not sure how I would be able to do this. I'm making some kind of syntactical or logical mistake which is confusing me. I'm pretty sure this should be able to work with interfaces, I'm wondering if there's something I'm misunderstanding of how to properly use interfaces

Comment: Every instance of `NetworkAggregation` is an object that implements `IAggregatePoint`, so this is perfectly good code: `IAggregatePoint pt = new NetworkAggregation`.  Not every `IAggregatePoint` is necessarily a `NetworkAggregation`, but anywhere you have a variable expecting a `IAggregatePoint` reference, you can pass a `NetworkAggregation` reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work. As long as a class implements the `IAggregatePoint` interface, an instance of that class can be provided to `ProcessAggregation` without any issues. You'll get a compiler error if you make a mistake (like trying to use a method that is from `NetworkAggregation` but not part of `IAggregatePoint` within `ProcessAggregation`).

You could also do the same thing with an abstract base class, as you mentioned.

It might be worthwhile to review the [C# language specification's documentation on interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface).

---

Edit - here's a simple, working example:

```
public interface IAggregatePoint 
{
}
    
public class NetworkAggregation : IAggregatePoint
{
}

public class AnotherAggregation
{
}

public void Test()
{
    // works because NetworkAggregation implements IAggregatePoint
    ProcessAggregation(new NetworkAggregation());
        
    // fails to compile (as expected) because AnotherAggregation 
    // doesn't implement IAggregatePoint
    ProcessAggregation(new AnotherAggregation()); 
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error though when I try to pass in objects implementing the Interface. For example: "Cannot convert type NetworkAggregation to IAggregatePoint"

Comment: What does your `NetworkAggregation` implementation look like?

Comment: @austinn That error message means that `NetworkAggregation` actually _doesn't_ implement the `IAggregatePoint` interface. See my update, I've added a simple example that demonstrates what I'm talking about. If your code doesn't compile, compare what I've got with your implementation and see what is different.

Comment: That would make sense, but I don't know if I can see a difference in the code I've implemented and your example though?

Comment: Could this be as a result of getting this NetworkAggregation object through the LINQ FirstOrDefault() method? This would mean that the returned object could be null.

Comment: No, C# will happily let you pass `null` into `ProcessAggregation` without complaining (try it out!). Does `NetworkAggregation` have `: IAggregatePoint` on its class definition? Do you have multiple versions of the `IAggregatePoint` interface in different namespaces?

Comment: First off, thank you so much for the help on this! Yes, NetworkAggregation does implement the IAggregatePoint interface (for example, if there's not a nullable DateTime? called AssessmentDate then there's a compiler issue). Both the NetworkAggregation class and IAggregatePoint (call it ProjectA) are in a different project than ProcessAggregation (ProjectB) if that matters. ProjectA has a using statement for the directory in ProjectB and has a reference to ProjectB as well.

Comment: That sounds like it's probably causing the problem. Based on your description, it doesn't seem possible for ProjectB to compile (since it doesn't reference ProjectA, but ProjectA is where `IAggregatePoint` is defined), unless ProjectB has its own definition of `IAggregatePoint`. If this is actually the case (and 
 `IAggregatePoint` is defined in both projects), then that's the issue - they are completely distinct types, even if they have the same name and have all the same properties. Try using the fully qualified class name (e.g. including the namespace) everywhere `IAggregatePoint` is used.

Comment: Whoops my mistake, it should really be "ProjectB is referencing ProjectA". ProjectB has other methods and whatnot already using the NetworkAggregation class which compile and work properly, meaning that ProcessAggregation in ProjectB also should have access to both IAggregatePoint and NetworkAggregation in ProjectA